# Aura Component could not catch a component event triggered from a child Aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, lightning-events

**Lightning Event:**

> tripEventer, attribute - trip, Trip__c

**Component Item:**

```
<aura:registerEvent name="openTripEvent" type="c:tripEventer"/>
<lightning:button class="slds-align_absolute-center" onclick="{!c.openTripAction}" label="Open Form"/><br/>
```

**Component Item Controller:**

```
openTripAction: function (component, event, helper) {
var action = component.getEvent('openTripEvent');
action.setParam('trip', component.get("v.trip"));
action.fire();
alert('gree from item button');
}
```

**Component Form:**

```
<aura:attribute type="String" name="test" default="nothing"/>
<aura:handler name="openTripEvent" action="{!c.handleOpenForm}" event="c:tripEventer"/>
```

**Component Form Controller:**

```
handleOpenForm: function (component, event, helper) {
component.set("v.test", "something");
alert('im here');
}
```

and I don't see alert 'i'm here, handleOpenForm js-action isn't fired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not specify the `name` attribute on an `aura:handler` for application events. This is specifically stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application_handling.htm):

> The handler for an application event won’t work if you set the name attribute in `<aura:handler>`. Use the name attribute only when you’re handling component events.

Removing the `name` attribute should resolve the problem.

Comment: but it's **component** event.i thought about it. so you think that [item component] inside  of [list component] can't catch [form component]? just change to application event?

Comment: Hey, Ivan, did this solve the issue for you? Hi @sfdcfox, I have a managed package to work with and I try to handle a component event (fired in the same way as in the example above - component.getEvent('openTripEvent')). And it couldn't get handled by the wrapping parent (another custom Aura component).

Comment: ah, as the managed event is declared as `type="APPLICATION"` I had to add the `name` in my case to be able to handle it. thanks sfdcofx, was helpful to see the correct way to implement the component events.